# How do I declare an impicitly typed variable in VB inline in an ASP.Net page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I want to do the following:

```
<%=var t = ViewData.Model%>
```

but in **`VB`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% Dim t = ViewData.Model %>
```

VB doesn't use a special keyword for implicitly typed variables... just Dim.